# In scala, is it possible to discourage the compiler from searching for Predef implicit first?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-compiler

This post:

[Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

described the implicit search precedence & algorithm used by modern scala compiler. In the above list, directly imported implicit functions should have higher precedence over scopes in associated types (e.g. defined in companion object)

This rule make sense most of the time, until the directly imported Predef.scala start to interfere:

```
    case class A(v: Int)

    object A {

      implicit class AFns(self: A) {

        def +(v2: Int): A = A(self.v + v2)
      }
    }

    val a1 = A(3)

    val b = a1 + 4

    assert(b == A(7))
```

The above example should compile successfully, but + operator override for ALL classes defined in Predef dominated the scene and caused all extensions with + operator to be useless (unless explicitly imported in a tighter scope). This is seriously annoying, is there a way to disable implicits in Predef or 'downgrade' its precedence?

The above experiment has been conducted in scala 2.12.12 & 2.13.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Importing `A._` explicitly [works](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/m8hLQZyvTfeAFxNQxWUGSA), but you can also use `-Yimports` by adding this to your build.sbt to leave out the `scala.Predef._` import:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Yimports", "java.lang", "scala")
```

After that, you can import everything from `Predef` except the `any2stringadd` class:

```
import Predef.{any2stringadd => _, _}
```

[Here's](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ekDV7Cn1S7mytLSMj4SlAQ) a Scastie.

Comment: Looks like thhis is the only way that works for the moment. Hope the Predef can have it's own precedence in the future